# How to install turicreate on windows 7?

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone tell me how to install turicreate on windows 7? I am using python of version 3.7. I have tried using pip install -U turicreate to install but failed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting from Turicreate website:

**Turi Create supports:**

- macOS 10.12+
- Linux (with glibc 2.12+)
- Windows 10 (via WSL)

**System Requirements**

- Python 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6
- Python 3.7 macOS only
- x86_64 architecture

So Windows 7 is not supported in this case.